# How was the Etch a Sketch art of Mona Lisa made for Elf?

Tags: props, elf

In the movie *Elf*, at one scene an Etch a Sketch is shown with an amazingly accurate rendition of the Mona Lisa drawn on it. Of course, it's really hard to draw on an Etch a Sketch, so I was wondering if someone actually created it on an Etch a Sketch, or if it was made some other way.

There are some other screens with less impressive Etch a Sketch drawings that would still be hard to make, including some that appear to be made in real-time by the character Buddy. I'm interested in how this was done too but I specifically want to know about the Mona Lisa.

Comment: I thought everybody could do that with their Etch a Sketch?  They probably just let some grip do it between takes.

Comment: While not an answer I would wager it was artificially done most likely with a physical method but possibly cgi as well. The reasoning for this is that even if it could be done by hand the risk of the pro/art becoming damaged and unusable as part of the filming would seem like two big of a risk.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As the Etch A Sketch is only shown finished, **I wager they simply fixed a transparent sheet of PVC or tracing paper with a print of the Mona Lisa onto the screen**:

[image: Portrait of Mona Lisa on Etch A Sketch]

In the scene it is only shown from a specific angle, possibly to hide differences in transparency or specular reflection. Moreover, it does not have the linear character that is typical of an Etch A Sketch drawing, even when done by a professional:

[image: "One-of-a-kind America Etch A Sketch print created by George Vlosich III."]
<sup>[source](https://gvartwork.com/products/american-etch-a-sketch-print)</sup>

However, later on in the film, we can [see](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PjyY7ePq39E) Buddy writing in cursive on the Etch A Sketch, **which must have been done using CGI**:

[image: Buddy writing a letter in cursive handwriting on the Etch A Sketch]

Comment: This is a lot of speculation.

Comment: @DJSpicyDeluxe It's speculation, but it's well-reasoned and has evidence to back it up. Now that I can compare the Mona Lisa drawing to an actual Etch-a-Sketch drawing, I'm pretty convinced that it was *not* actually drawn on an Etch-a-Sketch.